# What's the max value for Ping -W parameter?

Tags: linux, shell, ping

In my computer,I run the command  `ping 127.0.0.1 -c3 -W 5` and the result is ok.But when I run the command  `ping 127.0.0.1 -c3 -W 5000`,the result is not ok,the result is

> ping: bad linger time.

.So I wonder What's the max value for Ping -W parameter?

Comment: This is depending on your ping implementation which is very likey to be different depending on your operating system.

So as you have not given any information about your OS, this can not be answered.

try to execute `ping -V` to get information about your implementation

Comment: @Flo,the result of  `ping -V` is  `ping utility, iputils-s20160308`.The OS is `CentOS Linux release 7.6.1810 (Core)`

Answer (score 1):

Regarding your posted version i simply looked up the code [on github](https://github.com/iputils/iputils/blob/s20160308/ping.c) for release **s20160308**.

as seen in line **427**

```
if (lingertime < 0 || lingertime > INT_MAX/1000000)
```

the max value in your specific case is `INT_MAX/1000000`. Now `INT_MAX` can also depending on the implementation, but keeping the defaults it should be **2147483647** which would result in the answer of ping -W maximum value of

***2.147***

however in newer version of ping, this value is much higher.
so you might consider updating your `iputils`